# why my email is not sending using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

When I've Completed The Registration Process ,My Code Says That The Registration Was Successfull & Check Email For Login Link And Password.But When I'm Checking My Email I Could't See Any Email There.Here Is My Code.

```
    function send_email($name,$email,$password_generate,$login_link){
    $from_email="myemail@gmail.com";
    $data = array(
    'name'=> $name,
    'email'=> $email,
    'password'=> $password_generate,
     'login_url' => $login_link
    );

    $body = $this->load->view('backend/email',$data,TRUE);

    $config = array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'mail.mysite.com',
        'smtp_user' => $from_email,
        'smtp_pass' => 'mysite@Dhaka',
        'smtp_port' => 25,
        'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'UTF-8',
    'newline'   => "\r\n",
    'wordwrap'   => TRUE
    );
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from($from_email, 'mysite');
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject('Login Authentication');
    $this->email->message($body);
    if(!$this->email->send()){

    }
}
```

Whats Is The Problem ? ..I Need A Solution Badly ......

Comment: change $from_email to a valid @mysite.com address, if that works its an SMTP relaying issue.

Comment: I've Done That ....I've Given A Demo Address Here.. Actually I've Used A Valid @site.com address.But Still Its Not Working